# Evaluate OMR Sheet in android

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision, omr

I need help on how to design the Android app to evaluate the OMR sheet from the Android app. Actually, I have checked a lot of sites and nothing helped me. Can you help me where to start ?  What is the knowledge we need to build this kind of application ?